# proability mass function binomial distribution excersice

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

i have to solve this excercise, but i'm confussed how to find the probability mass function and if it is an binomial distribution with a bernoulli trials.
A mouse is placed in a model with five doors. Each door opens when the mouse is detected by a sensor, this has a probability 0.7; the operation of the doors is independent of each other. The following figure shows the basic outline of the model that the mouse will enter. 
e= entry s=sensor p=door l= arrival

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QmwK.png)

If the random variable is: X: = "The number of direct paths from the sensor to arrival available on the model"
direct path: in which there is no need to travel a section of the route more than once.

the question is what is the probability mass function of the problem?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, a direct path is one where one the first detection of the sensor, the appropriate doors open up to create a straight path from $S$ to $L$. Hence

$$P(X=0) : \text{No direct paths}$$
$$P(X=1) : \text{Exactly one direct path}\\.\\.\\.\\P(X=4) : \text{Exactly 4 direct paths}$$

Now, you just consider each case separately. For example, for $X=0$, which gates need to be shut, and which can be open? Can you proceed?

Comment: Thank you,  I could solve the exercise in the way that you proposed :)